# Bloc pattern in Flutter with Single page opening multiple times

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

How do I implement `Bloc` pattern in Flutter where I want to open a page multiple times.

Suppose I have a detailed list, and from the detailed list I can click on an item and open the detail page of Item `A`.

The detail page has a `bloc` for it. From detail page of item `A` I can open detail page of item `B` and from detail that I can open detail page of item `A`.

Page stack: `(1)A -> (2)B -> (3)A`

Now for every invocation of a new detail page, should I create a new bloc? or should I have a global `detail_bloc` that manages a stack of opened detail pages. Also I need a way to update details of previous opened page of item `(1)A` if there are any changes (due to user input) on page of top level item `(3)A`.

Comment: Maybe think about it as separate by the business logic. If you just create a bloc for each page, I'm not sure that feels right, but it can depend. From the question, it's not clear if you even need BLoC at all, so it's quite difficult to answer that with the info given. Maybe include a bit more about the separate areas and states involved, rather than just the pages ?

Comment: @Ian The detail page will receive an id from the main list which will be used to make a network request, think of it as a detail page of a shopping app, from this detail page you have recommended products with which you can open other detail pages as well.

Comment: See if this example helps at all https://github.com/filiph/state_experiments/tree/master/shared/lib/src/bloc_complex

Comment: I'm not 100% clear from your question, but it seems like you want to access information saved in the bloc from detail page A once you are in page B, in which case you will need to use a single bloc. What state data are you saving in the bloc and where do you subsequently need to access this data from?